# how do i get data from function, var in scripts using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<script defer="">
    window.__CURRENT_SITE__ = window.__CURRENT_SITE__ || "videoblocks";
window.__CURRENT_PATH__ = window.__CURRENT_PATH__ || "\/video\/stock\/overheated-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-high-temperature-indoors-belnttknlk6yv56x6";
window.__CURRENT_SEARCH_PARAMS__ = window.__CURRENT_SEARCH_PARAMS__ || "?";
    (function() {
        var initialState8277 = {"auth":{"isLoggedIn":false,"isMobile":false,"user":null,"subscription":null,"primarySubscription":null,"videoSubscription":null,"audioSubscription":null,"imageSubscription":null,"permissions":{"makerHooksVisible":false,"hasFolderAccess":false},"featureFlags":{"licenseRevampTest":false,"shouldShowMakerActionsHook":false}},"details":{"stockItem":{"id":10852901,"contentClass":"video","contentId":338169628,"assetId":"SBV-338169628","title":"Overheated young african american lady suffering from high temperature indoors.","description":null,"detailsUrl":"\/video\/stock\/overheated-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-high-temperature-indoors-belnttknlk6yv56x6","previewUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/watermarks\/video\/Sz9LmzxmBjyscquj0\/videoblocks-overheated-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-high-temperature-indoors_bxo5ta1nu__b14441d66874772d2a7b34dde20873a9__P360.mp4","smallPreviewUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/watermarks\/video\/Sz9LmzxmBjyscquj0\/videoblocks-overheated-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-high-temperature-indoors_bxo5ta1nu__b14441d66874772d2a7b34dde20873a9__P180.mp4","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/thumbnails\/video\/Sz9LmzxmBjyscquj0\/videoblocks-overheated-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-high-temperature-indoors_bxo5ta1nu_thumbnail-180_01.jpg","isMarketPlaceItem":false,"contributorPortalId":"BelnTTkNLk6yv56x6","distributionType":"RS","expirationDate":null,"shouldStockItemHaveNewFlag":false,"shouldStockItemHaveStaffPickFlag":false,"dateAdded":"2020-02-23 05:02:16","contentType":"footage","dateDistributionTypeUpdated":"2020-02-23 15:02:16","isActive":true,"mediumImageUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/thumbnails\/video\/Sz9LmzxmBjyscquj0\/videoblocks-overheated-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-high-temperature-indoors_bxo5ta1nu_thumbnail-360_01.jpg","duration":14,"is360":false,"isTemplate":false,"collapsedSetId":"","numCollapses":null,"rating":0,"downloads":1247,"hasTalentReleased":true,"hasPropertyReleased":false,"keywords":["african","african american","alone","biracial","discomfort","emotion","expression","female","from","girl","heat","high temperature","home","hot","indoors","lady","millennial","mixed","multiracial","overheated","people","person","portrait","problem","room","sit","sofa","stressed","suffer","suffering","uncomfortable","unhappy","unpleasant","unwell","upset","woman","young"],"hasAlphaChannel":false,"maxResolution":null,"isEditorial":false,"categories":[{"id":10,"groupId":189304,"urlId":"people","name":"People","description":"Download royalty free stock footage video clips of people.","type":"category","source":"auto","searchIndexable":true,"searchType":"footage","active":true,"dateAdded":"2014-10-19T23:35:05.000Z","dateUpdated":"2021-01-21T16:11:04.441Z","contributorId":null,"stockContributorId":null,"position":null,"isHomepageCollection":null,"showInApi":false}],"contributor":{"username":"fizkes","portfolioLink":"https:\/\/www.storyblocks.com\/video\/portfolio\/fizkes"}},"stockItemFormats":[{"id":null,"label":"4KMOV","prettyLabel":"4K MOV","filesize":"1501 MB","filename":"videoblocks-overheated-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-high-temperature-indoors_Bxo5Ta1NU.mov","resolution":"4096 x 2160","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346730940\/4KMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346730940\/4KMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346730940\/4KMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMOV","prettyLabel":"HD MOV","filesize":"159.4 MB","filename":"videoblocks-61a620ba428c7c51d487da72_stqmh0u9tk_1080__D.mov","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346730940\/HDMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346730940\/HDMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346730940\/HDMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMP4","prettyLabel":"HD MP4","filesize":"3.9 MB","filename":"videoblocks-61a620ba428c7c51d487da72_stqmh0u9tk_1080__D.mp4","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346730940\/HDMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346730940\/HDMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346730940\/HDMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"}],"selectedAcquisitionOption":[{"id":null,"label":"4KMOV","prettyLabel":"4K MOV","filesize":"1342.4 MB","filename":"videoblocks-61a620ba428c7c51d487da72_STQMh0U9tK.mov","resolution":"3840 x 2160","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346730940\/4KMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346730940\/4KMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346730940\/4KMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"4KMP4","prettyLabel":"4K MP4","filesize":"17.7 MB","filename":"videoblocks-61a620ba428c7c51d487da72_stqmh0u9tk_2160__D.mp4","resolution":"3840 x 2160","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346730940\/4KMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346730940\/4KMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346730940\/4KMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMOV","prettyLabel":"HD MOV","filesize":"159.4 MB","filename":"videoblocks-61a620ba428c7c51d487da72_stqmh0u9tk_1080__D.mov","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346730940\/HDMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346730940\/HDMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346730940\/HDMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMP4","prettyLabel":"HD MP4","filesize":"3.9 MB","filename":"videoblocks-61a620ba428c7c51d487da72_stqmh0u9tk_1080__D.mp4","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346730940\/HDMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346730940\/HDMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346730940\/HDMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"}],"isFavorite":false,"topTags":[],"stockItemArtists":[],"moods":[],"genres":[]},{"stockItem":{"id":346653750,"contentClass":"video","contentId":346653750,"assetId":"SBV-346653750","title":"High blood pressure. Close up portrait of sad unhappy african american lady suffering from acute headache","description":null,"detailsUrl":"\/video\/stock\/high-blood-pressure-close-up-portrait-of-sad-unhappy-african-american-lady-suffering-from-acute-headache-h3wb0l6zkktivcy0i","previewUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/watermarks\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_hh3xcgtft__1911c24512c9600378e44fd3fc60226a__P360.mp4","smallPreviewUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/watermarks\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_hh3xcgtft__1911c24512c9600378e44fd3fc60226a__P180.mp4","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/thumbnails\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_hh3xcgtft_thumbnail-180_01.jpg","isMarketPlaceItem":false,"contributorPortalId":"H3WB0l6zKktivcy0i","distributionType":"RS","expirationDate":null,"shouldStockItemHaveNewFlag":false,"shouldStockItemHaveStaffPickFlag":false,"dateAdded":"2021-09-13 12:37:20","contentType":"footage","dateDistributionTypeUpdated":"2021-09-13 16:37:21","isActive":true,"mediumImageUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/thumbnails\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_hh3xcgtft_thumbnail-360_01.jpg","duration":16,"is360":false,"isTemplate":false,"collapsedSetId":"","numCollapses":null},"stockItemFormats":[{"id":null,"label":"4KMOV","prettyLabel":"4K MOV","filesize":"1338.2 MB","filename":"videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_Hh3XCgTft.mov","resolution":"3840 x 2160","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346653750\/4KMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346653750\/4KMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346653750\/4KMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"4KMP4","prettyLabel":"4K MP4","filesize":"20.3 MB","filename":"videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_hh3xcgtft_2160__D.mp4","resolution":"3840 x 2160","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346653750\/4KMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346653750\/4KMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346653750\/4KMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMOV","prettyLabel":"HD MOV","filesize":"328.2 MB","filename":"videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_hh3xcgtft_1080__D.mov","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346653750\/HDMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346653750\/HDMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346653750\/HDMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMP4","prettyLabel":"HD MP4","filesize":"3.6 MB","filename":"videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_hh3xcgtft_1080__D.mp4","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346653750\/HDMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346653750\/HDMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346653750\/HDMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"}],"selectedAcquisitionOption":[{"id":null,"label":"4KMOV","prettyLabel":"4K MOV","filesize":"1338.2 MB","filename":"videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_Hh3XCgTft.mov","resolution":"3840 x 2160","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346653750\/4KMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346653750\/4KMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346653750\/4KMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"4KMP4","prettyLabel":"4K MP4","filesize":"20.3 MB","filename":"videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_hh3xcgtft_2160__D.mp4","resolution":"3840 x 2160","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346653750\/4KMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346653750\/4KMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346653750\/4KMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMOV","prettyLabel":"HD MOV","filesize":"328.2 MB","filename":"videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_hh3xcgtft_1080__D.mov","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346653750\/HDMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346653750\/HDMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346653750\/HDMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMP4","prettyLabel":"HD MP4","filesize":"3.6 MB","filename":"videoblocks-613f65163396b06b98621838_hh3xcgtft_1080__D.mp4","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346653750\/HDMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346653750\/HDMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346653750\/HDMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"}],"isFavorite":false,"topTags":[],"stockItemArtists":[],"moods":[],"genres":[]},{"stockItem":{"id":10898291,"contentClass":"video","contentId":338435819,"assetId":"SBV-338435819","title":"Unhealthy young african american woman suffering from flu.","description":null,"detailsUrl":"\/video\/stock\/unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu-soi03trjikaihfomm","previewUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/watermarks\/video\/Sz9LmzxmBjyscquj0\/videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_bdba3yhsi__56c4021384112fbb32db144fbc3fdac6__P360.mp4","smallPreviewUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/watermarks\/video\/Sz9LmzxmBjyscquj0\/videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_bdba3yhsi__56c4021384112fbb32db144fbc3fdac6__P180.mp4","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/thumbnails\/video\/Sz9LmzxmBjyscquj0\/videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_bdba3yhsi_thumbnail-180_01.jpg","isMarketPlaceItem":false,"contributorPortalId":"SOI03trjIkaihfomm","distributionType":"RS","expirationDate":null,"shouldStockItemHaveNewFlag":false,"shouldStockItemHaveStaffPickFlag":false,"dateAdded":"2020-05-22 13:33:01","contentType":"footage","dateDistributionTypeUpdated":"2020-05-22 21:33:01","isActive":true,"mediumImageUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/thumbnails\/video\/Sz9LmzxmBjyscquj0\/videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_bdba3yhsi_thumbnail-360_01.jpg","duration":12,"is360":false,"isTemplate":false,"collapsedSetId":"","numCollapses":null},"stockItemFormats":[{"id":null,"label":"4KMOV","prettyLabel":"4K MOV","filesize":"1193 MB","filename":"videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_BdBa3YHsI.mov","resolution":"4096 x 2160","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/10898291\/4KMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/10898291\/4KMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/10898291\/4KMOV","frameRate":"29.97 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"4KMP4","prettyLabel":"4K MP4","filesize":"12.8 MB","filename":"videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_bdba3yhsi_2160__D.mp4","resolution":"3840 x 2160","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/10898291\/4KMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/10898291\/4KMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/10898291\/4KMP4","frameRate":"29.97 fps","codec":"h264"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMOV","prettyLabel":"HD MOV","filesize":"189.6 MB","filename":"videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_bdba3yhsi_1080__D.mov","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/10898291\/HDMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/10898291\/HDMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/10898291\/HDMOV","frameRate":"29.97 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMP4","prettyLabel":"HD MP4","filesize":"3.4 MB","filename":"videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_bdba3yhsi_1080__D.mp4","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/10898291\/HDMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/10898291\/HDMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/10898291\/HDMP4","frameRate":"29.97 fps","codec":"h264"}],"selectedAcquisitionOption":[{"id":null,"label":"4KMOV","prettyLabel":"4K MOV","filesize":"1193 MB","filename":"videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_BdBa3YHsI.mov","resolution":"4096 x 2160","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/10898291\/4KMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/10898291\/4KMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/10898291\/4KMOV","frameRate":"29.97 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"4KMP4","prettyLabel":"4K MP4","filesize":"12.8 MB","filename":"videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_bdba3yhsi_2160__D.mp4","resolution":"3840 x 2160","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/10898291\/4KMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/10898291\/4KMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/10898291\/4KMP4","frameRate":"29.97 fps","codec":"h264"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMOV","prettyLabel":"HD MOV","filesize":"189.6 MB","filename":"videoblocks-unhealthy-young-african-american-woman-suffering-from-flu_bdba3yhsi_1080__D.mov","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346673065\/HDMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346673065\/HDMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346673065\/HDMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMP4","prettyLabel":"HD MP4","filesize":"2.5 MB","filename":"videoblocks-615ade16105bea1663ce70d6_h6a8bj_vk_1080__D.mp4","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346673065\/HDMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346673065\/HDMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346673065\/HDMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"}],"selectedAcquisitionOption":[{"id":null,"label":"4KMOV","prettyLabel":"4K MOV","filesize":"860.1 MB","filename":"videoblocks-615ade16105bea1663ce70d6_H6a8bj_VK.mov","resolution":"3840 x 2160","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346673065\/4KMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346673065\/4KMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346673065\/4KMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"4KMP4","prettyLabel":"4K MP4","filesize":"9.4 MB","filename":"videoblocks-615ade16105bea1663ce70d6_h6a8bj_vk_2160__D.mp4","resolution":"3840 x 2160","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"4K","formatName":"4KMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346673065\/4KMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346673065\/4KMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346673065\/4KMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMOV","prettyLabel":"HD MOV","filesize":"133.6 MB","filename":"videoblocks-615ade16105bea1663ce70d6_h6a8bj_vk_1080__D.mov","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346673065\/HDMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346673065\/HDMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346673065\/HDMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMP4","prettyLabel":"HD MP4","filesize":"2.5 MB","filename":"videoblocks-615ade16105bea1663ce70d6_h6a8bj_vk_1080__D.mp4","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/346673065\/HDMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/346673065\/HDMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/346673065\/HDMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"}],"isFavorite":false,"topTags":[],"stockItemArtists":[],"moods":[],"genres":[]},{"stockItem":{"id":11122603,"contentClass":"video","contentId":346560856,"assetId":"SBV-346560856","title":"Young african american lady suffering from strong abdominal ache, lying on white bed wearing pajamas and frowning","description":null,"detailsUrl":"\/video\/stock\/young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning-rb-eiawtokqs0wd2g","previewUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/watermarks\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_ssjqitw6d__b6866d051bcc3a7bbf67d50c5f8d939b__P360.mp4","smallPreviewUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/watermarks\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_ssjqitw6d__b6866d051bcc3a7bbf67d50c5f8d939b__P180.mp4","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/thumbnails\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_ssjqitw6d_thumbnail-180_01.jpg","isMarketPlaceItem":false,"contributorPortalId":"rB-EiaWTOkqs0wd2g","distributionType":"RS","expirationDate":null,"shouldStockItemHaveNewFlag":false,"shouldStockItemHaveStaffPickFlag":false,"dateAdded":"2021-07-06 08:23:05","contentType":"footage","dateDistributionTypeUpdated":"2021-07-06 12:23:05","isActive":true,"mediumImageUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/thumbnails\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_ssjqitw6d_thumbnail-360_01.jpg","duration":19,"is360":false,"isTemplate":false,"collapsedSetId":"","numCollapses":null},"stockItemFormats":[{"id":null,"label":"HDMOV","prettyLabel":"HD MOV","filesize":"396.9 MB","filename":"videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_SSjQiTW6d.mov","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/11122603\/HDMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/11122603\/HDMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/11122603\/HDMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMP4","prettyLabel":"HD MP4","filesize":"3.2 MB","filename":"videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_ssjqitw6d_1080__D.mp4","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/11122603\/HDMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/11122603\/HDMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/11122603\/HDMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"}],"selectedAcquisitionOption":[{"id":null,"label":"HDMOV","prettyLabel":"HD MOV","filesize":"396.9 MB","filename":"videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_SSjQiTW6d.mov","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/11122603\/HDMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/11122603\/HDMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/11122603\/HDMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"prores"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMP4","prettyLabel":"HD MP4","filesize":"3.2 MB","filename":"videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_ssjqitw6d_1080__D.mp4","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/11122603\/HDMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/11122603\/HDMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/11122603\/HDMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"}],"isFavorite":false,"topTags":[],"stockItemArtists":[],"moods":[],"genres":[]},{"stockItem":{"id":11126650,"contentClass":"video","contentId":346565766,"assetId":"SBV-346565766","title":"Young african american lady suffering from strong abdominal ache, lying on white bed wearing pajamas and frowning","description":null,"detailsUrl":"\/video\/stock\/young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning-sbr7rwkpukr09hxdi","previewUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/watermarks\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_rbumswkpu__cb16a49f7af5326267be1b675680fc9f__P360.mp4","smallPreviewUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/watermarks\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_rbumswkpu__cb16a49f7af5326267be1b675680fc9f__P180.mp4","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/thumbnails\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_rbumswkpu_thumbnail-180_01.jpg","isMarketPlaceItem":false,"contributorPortalId":"SBR7rwKpukr09hxdi","distributionType":"RS","expirationDate":null,"shouldStockItemHaveNewFlag":false,"shouldStockItemHaveStaffPickFlag":false,"dateAdded":"2021-07-12 02:45:58","contentType":"footage","dateDistributionTypeUpdated":"2021-07-12 06:45:58","isActive":true,"mediumImageUrl":"https:\/\/dm0qx8t0i9gc9.cloudfront.net\/thumbnails\/video\/SuFLR1_Nwkex4zo1y\/videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_rbumswkpu_thumbnail-360_01.jpg","duration":19,"is360":false,"isTemplate":false,"collapsedSetId":"","numCollapses":null},"stockItemFormats":[{"id":null,"label":"HDMOV","prettyLabel":"HD MOV","filesize":"396.9 MB","filename":"videoblocks-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-strong-abdominal-ache-lying-on-white-bed-wearing-pajamas-and-frowning_rBumSwKpu.mov","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mov","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMOV","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/4267085\/HDMOV","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/4267085\/HDMOV","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/4267085\/HDMOV","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"mjpeg"},{"id":null,"label":"HDMP4","prettyLabel":"HD MP4","filesize":"6.6 MB","filename":"videoblocks-a-young-sick-man-suffering-from-influenza-measuring-temperature-and-drinking-medicine_rvme1wxmeb_1080__D.mp4","resolution":"1920 x 1080","fileExtension":"mp4","quality":"HD","formatName":"HDMP4","downloadAjaxUrl":"\/video\/download-ajax\/4267085\/HDMP4","downloadUrl":"\/video\/download\/4267085\/HDMP4","exportUrl":"\/video\/cloud-export\/4267085\/HDMP4","frameRate":"25 fps","codec":"h264"}],"isFavorite":false,"topTags":[],"stockItemArtists":[],"moods":[],"genres":[]}],"memberDownloadDate":"","makerHooks":{"makerPreCreateProjectRoute":"https:\/\/maker.storyblocks.com\/edit?videoIds=10852901","makerSignupRoute":"https:\/\/www.storyblocks.com\/join\/become-user\/maker\/edit?videoIds=10852901"},"canDownload":false,"mvtPages":{"premiere-pro-templates":"\/video\/premiere-pro-templates","apple-motion-templates":"\/video\/apple-motion-templates","intro":"\/video\/after-effects-templates\/intros","green-screen":"\/video\/footage\/green-screen","lower-thirds":"\/video\/after-effects-templates\/lower-thirds"},"canExportToCloud":false,"cloudExportSubfolders":[]}};       

</script>
```

I am new in python, bs4

here is the json data want to scrape, from that **script defer > var initialState > {"stockItem":{"id":217104**, only i want **217104 or "downloadAjaxUrl":"/video/download-ajax/10852901/4KMP4" or more elements**. what should i do?

I have tried these attempts:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.storyblocks.com/video/stock/overheated-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-high-temperature-indoors-belnttknlk6yv56x6'

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36', 'origin': URL}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features='lxml')

script = soup.select('body > div.wrapper > script:nth-child(6)')
# or
function = soup.find_all('script')[24]

print(script)
print(function)
```

#attempt 1

```
f = function[30:] # 30 for check
print(f)
```

#output

```
    return self.attrs[key]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

#attempt 2

```
    f = function["stockItem"]
    print(f)
```

#output

```
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'stockItem'
```

can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You'd use regular expression to pull out that json pattern.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json

URL = 'https://www.storyblocks.com/video/stock/overheated-young-african-american-lady-suffering-from-high-temperature-indoors-belnttknlk6yv56x6'

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36', 'origin': URL}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features='lxml')

script = soup.find_all('script', {'defer':''})
# or
function = soup.find_all('script')[24]


jsonStr = re.search('var initialState.*= ({.*})', str(function)).group(1)
jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

**Output:**

```
stockItem = jsonData['details']['stockItem']
print(stockItem['id'])

10852901
```

Comment: omg, thank you so much. you are a life savior. love you man <3

Comment: be sure to accept the solution.